# more deails for internal errors

Tags: 13.10, error-handling

I've been getting a lot of these internal errors with 13.10. When I click to get more info it only says

```
/user/bin/application-ubuntu-tried-to-run
```

Is there a way to get more details about why `application-ubuntu-tried-to-run` caused an error, what that error was, exit codes/return values, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Those messages are created by `apport`, which logs more details in `/var/log/apport.log`. Checking there should at least give you an idea of what happened.

Generally speaking, `~/.xsession-errors` is also a good source of information about recent application errors.